# scramble function won't output

Tags: python, function, scramble

this function will not give me an output when tested in python's IDLE:

```
import random

def scramble(string):

rlist = []

 while len(rlist) < len(string):

        n = random.randint(0, len(string) - 1)
        if rlist.count(string[n]) < string.count(string[n]):
            rlist += string[n]
    rstring = str(rlist)        
    return rstring 

scramble('sdfa')
```

I've spent a long time trying to figure out the problem, but the code seems good to me.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't look correct.

Comment: You do not print the result on the screen, therefore it is normal it does not output anything. Also note that there is already a shuffle function in the random module.

Answer (score 0):

Correctly formatting this seems to solve the problem.

```
import random

def scramble(string):
   rlist = []
   while len(rlist) < len(string):
      n = random.randint(0, len(string) - 1)
      if rlist.count(string[n]) < string.count(string[n]):
         rlist += string[n]
   rstring = str(rlist)        
   return rstring
print(scramble('sdfa'))
```

In Python, indentation is just as important as good syntax :)
By the way, as @Vincent Savard said, you did not print the result. In your scramble() you returned a string, but you did not do anything with said string.

Comment: His original post had no formatting at all, I wouldn't blame the problem on indentation. Someone edited it, he may have not indented it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

Do not use `string` as the argument name, it could clash with the [standard module `string`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#module-string).

You probably do not want to return an `str()` of the list, which results in something like

```
>>> rlist = ['s', 'a', 'f', 'd']
>>> str(rlist)
>>> "['s', 'a', 'f', 'd']"
```

Instead, to get a scrambled string result, use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> rlist = ['s', 'a', 'f', 'd']
>>> ''.join(rlist)
'safd'
>>>
```

The last 2 lines of `scramble` can be joined in a single `return`:

```
return str(rlist)
```

or

```
return ''.join(rlist)
```